# In search for a way to ask and get helped

Tags: discussion, questions

I have been active user on stackoverflow for about 1.5 years now. I have helped **many** users solve their problems and I always try to help everyone I can. However everytime **I** ask a question it either gets downvotes and then gets closed(like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15634322/812912)) or hardly gets any activity at all(like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13122525/812912) and several others I already deleted). I tried adding bounties but all I got was one fake answer trying to get the bounty in the last day. I find this extremely demotivating. Of course while answering questions I learn new things and it is definitely useful for me, but I would also like to believe that should someday I need help someone will help me in return.

Why [asking about a library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14645665/812912) that can do the job I need "not constructive". I have seen many similar questions and usually the best source you can trust for such things is the experience other users have with similar things?

What am I doing wrong? I believe out of 40 questions I asked maybe only 5-6 got me an answer that was really helpful to me. Of course one could say that I am asking the questions in a wrong manner. Well, if I see a user that did not ask the right question or did not put it in the best way I give feedback and I try to improve the question so that he/she gets the best help possible.

Please before voting to close **this** question take a minute and try to explaing what is wrong here. Somehow I wish this community could be useful to everyone.

Comment: 24 questions.  2 closed, 2 not answered.  That's actually not too bad IMO, though you do mention deleting some.  [I don't recommend doing that.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: I have deleted more than 10 now. Each time its the same - I get tons of downvotes no reasoning and question gets closed.

Comment: @izomorphius Like I said, don't do that or you'll end up question banned.

Comment: You only have 4 deleted questions on Stack Overflow, and only 2 of those were deleted by you.  You've also accepted answers to all of your questions that *have* answers (so all but 2 of the non-deleted ones, the 2 you linked to).  I'm really not sure what you're on about here.

Comment: @BilltheLizard thanks for summing that up. Maybe my approach is a bit wrong on accepting answers. I have the habbit of always accepting the best answer first to keep my accept rate high(hoping to get better answers) and second because in most cases that answers is good only that it does not solve my particular problem

Comment: @Seth: that is extremely unlikely.

Comment: If the answer doesn't answer the question, then don't accept.

Answer (score 2):

When you get no answers there are three possible reasons:

- users don't understand the question
- the question should have been on another site
- the question is too hard

The first case is often accompanied with down and close votes. The solution is to edit the question so more users can understand it.

The second case, is often accompanied with migration votes.  The solution is to let it migrate and monitor it on the other site. Possibly editing it for clarity.

The last case is a tough one. You could edit to show more information. And possibly use a bounty for more attention. But real hard questions are hard to answer. And sometimes the right person is not available.

Comment: Truth is in one of the comments I found out my second question is better suited on Server Fault and I hope to get some activity there. Truth is I never heard about this site before.

Comment: There is always a first for anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "What do you recommend..." type questions is that they quite often descend into either a debate over what the best solution is, or turn into a bunch of people posting links to off-site locations with little or no additional content.

Regarding the debate, everyone has an opinion, and all of those opinions matter (especially to the person having them). However, what is "best" or "recommended" depends too much on specific needs of a project or other information that we don't have access to, and which would make the question entirely too long and complex to be answered here.

As far as turning into a link collection, if the majority of the content of an answer is a link to an external, and that outside link become unavailable for some reason (for instance, the site is off-line or gets moved in the future), the link becomes meaningless, and therefore so does the answer. For instance, I just flagged an answer in the last few minutes (made by a user who should know better) that consisted entirely of:

```
Also, <link> and <link>.
```

Both of the indicated links were to an external site. What value remains in that answer if the destination site is not there?

Comment: That also demonstrates credibility. Half the time I go to those link sites, they're not geared for someone trying to understand what they don't currently understand (looking at you MSDN). So in all likelyhood the poster did a Google search and posted the first link.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat tangential, but I think it is important to address a couple of your comments.

> ...I have the habit of always accepting the best answer first to keep
>   my accept rate high(hoping to get better answers...

Don't do that. [There is no accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) any more, and accepting an unhelpful answer decreases your question's attractiveness to future answerers. It makes it less likely that someone who can provide the solution will visit your answer.

> I have deleted more than 10 now. Each time its the same - I get tons
>   of downvotes no reasoning and question gets closed.

Please don't delete questions in response to downvotes. It brings your neck an inch closer to the banbot's scythe, and doesn't help you find out what went wrong.

If you get tons of downvotes and no explanation (which does occasionally happen, but not consistently) go through the FAQ and see if your question violates any of the guidelines. If you can't identify any problems with your question, ask a question on Meta from a neutral perspective. Highlight the fact that you haven't received any feedback, and try to be open to constructive criticism.

Once you have identified any problems, go back to your questions and edit them. Also apply the information gleaned to future questions.

Comment: what if I don't identify any problems?

Comment: There is no accept rate any more? I did not notice that. Thanks for pointing it out to me. It was total nonsense imho.

Comment: @izomorphius Then either you're the victim of some freak of probability, or you aren't looking hard enough. Also, see my edit.

Comment: no I simply have not ask anything for a long while and I rarely even noticed accept rate before.

Comment: @izomorphius Sorry, I was responding to your first comment there. Took a while to type out.

Answer (score 0):

[Hardly any activity at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13122525/812912)

In this case, people in the windows tag may not know anything about virtualization, and the tags [virtualization](/questions/tagged/virtualization) and [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi) only have 100 followers each, and about 60% answer rate. [snapshot](/questions/tagged/snapshot) has 3 followers.

Your chances for an answer look pretty dismal.

Compare that to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or so, where the answer rate is much higher.

[Asking about a library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14645665/812912)

This borders on Shopping questions, which are more than highly discouraged.

Comment: Truth is in one of the comments I found out my second question is better suited on Server Fault and I hope to get some activity there. Truth is I never heard about this site before.